# Finding frequency of words after stemming in Python

Tags: python, data-cleaning, word-frequency

I am doing a data cleaning task on a text file full of sentences. After stemming these sentences I would like to get the frequency of the words in my stemmed list. However I am encountering a problem as when printing the stemmed list, stem_list,  I am obtaining a list for every sentence like so :

```
[u'anyon', u'think', u'forgotten', u'day', u'parti', u'friend', u'friend', u'paymast', u'us', u'longer', u'memori']

[u'valu', u'friend', u'bought', u'properti', u'actual', u'relev', u'repres', u'actual', u'valu', u'properti']

[u'monster', u'wreck', u'reef', u'cargo', u'vessel', u'week', u'passeng', u'ship', u'least', u'24', u'hour', u'upload', u'com']
```

I would like to obtain the frequency of all of the words but I am only obtaining the frequency per sentence by using the following code:

```
   fdist = nltk.FreqDist(stem_list)
   for word, frequency in fdist.most_common(50):
         print(u'{};{}'.format(word, frequency))
```

This is producing the following output: 
           **friend;2**
paymast;1
longer;1
memori;1
parti;1
us;1
day;1
anyon;1
forgotten;1
think;1
actual;2
properti;2
valu;2
**friend;1**
repres;1
relev;1
bought;1
week;1
cargo;1
monster;1
hour;1
wreck;1
upload;1
passeng;1
least;1
reef;1
24;1
vessel;1
ship;1
com;1
within;1
area;1
territori;1
custom;1
water;1
3;1

The word 'friend' is being counted twice since it is in two different sentences. How would I be able to make it count friend once and display friend;3 in this case?

Comment: You should definitvely have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: The way you define `stem_list` has invalid syntax. Please provide a valid definition.

Answer (score 0):

You could just concatenate everything in one list :

```
stem_list = [inner for outer in stem_list for inner in outer]
```

and process the same way you do.

Otherwise, you could keep the same code but instead of printing you create a dict and populate it with values you get. Each time you get a new word, you create the key, then you add the value.

```
all_words_count = dict()
for word, frequency in fdist.most_common(50):
    if word in all_words_count : # Already found
        all_words_count[word] += frequency
    else : # Not found yet
        all_words_count[word] = frequency

for word in all_words_count : 
    print(u'{};{}'.format(word, all_words_count[word]))
```

Comment: I have tried doing that but it ends up printing out each letter separately, like so: [u'a', u'n', u'y', u'o', u'n', u't', u'h', u'i', u'n', u'k', u'f', u'o', u'r', u'g', u'o', u't', u't', u'e', u'n', u'd', u'a', u'y', u'p', u'a', u'r', u't', u'i', u'f', u'r', u'i', u'e', u'n', u'd', u'f', u'r', u'i', u'e', u'n', u'd', u'p', u'a', u'y', u'm', u'a', u's', u't', u'u', u's', u'l', u'o', u'n', u'g', u'e', u'r', u'm', u'e', u'm', u'o', u'r', u'i']

Comment: What exactly is stem_list ? Is it a list of list ? Your structure in your post is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for that, they are word-vectors since I had tokenized my text file (containing the sentences) before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easyest way is to combine the arrays before passing it to the function.

```
allwords = [inner for outer in stem_list for inner in outer]

fdist = nltk.FreqDist(allwords)
    for word, frequency in fdist.most_common(50):
        print(y'{};{}'.format(word, frequency))
```

or shorter:

```
fdist = nltk.FreqDist([inner for outer in stem_list for inner in outer])
    for word, frequency in fdist.most_common(50):
        print(y'{};{}'.format(word, frequency))
```

I think your input looks like:

```
stem_list = [[u'anyon', u'think', u'forgotten', u'day', u'parti', u'friend', u'friend', u'paymast', u'us', u'longer', u'memori'],

            [u'valu', u'friend', u'bought', u'properti', u'actual', u'relev', u'repres', u'actual', u'valu', u'properti'],

            [u'monster', u'wreck', u'reef', u'cargo', u'vessel', u'week', u'passeng', u'ship', u'least', u'24', u'hour', u'upload', u'com'],

            [.....], etc for the other sentences ]
```

so you have two arrays - first for sentences and second for words in sentenc. With allwords = [inner for outer in stem_list for inner in outer] you run through the sentences and combine them as one array of words.

Comment: `allwords = [sent for sent in stem_list]` will not do anything. It will take the inner list and then put it in list. The `stem_list` remain the same except it's also being referenced by `allwords`

Comment: Thanks, have corrected it with the ieterrator form iFlo - havn't checked it.

Answer (score 0):

You could [flatten your 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) first with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(chain.from_iterable(stem_list)):
    for word, frequency in fdist.most_common(50):
        print(u'{};{}'.format(word, frequency))
```